# Why is my Prolog exercise not trying other solutions?

Tags: list, prolog, shuffle

I'm trying a college assignment in Prolog, and I have some questions. This is the exercise text, I hope it's clear I'm translating from Italian:

> Write a predicate `arrange(List1, List2, K)` that when given a `List1` of at least two elements with only numbers between the range `[0..100]`, is satisfied when `List2` is a list obtained re-shuffling the elements of `List1` in a way that the absolute difference between two consecutive elements is always greater than `K`.

Example:

```
?- arrange([1, 2, 3], L2, 0). 
L2 = [1, 2, 3];
L2 = [1, 3, 2];
L2 = [2, 1, 3];
L2 = [2, 3, 1];
L2 = [3, 1, 2];
L2 = [3, 2, 1];
```

I've tried to create my own solution, but it doesn't give me all the possible results, instead, I get only one of the possible result. I also have a colleague's solution that gives all the results, but it has one problem that I was trying to fix.

Here's my solution:

```
arrange(L1,L3,Diff):-
    arrange(L1,[],L3,Diff).
arrange(L1,L2,L3,Diff):-
    same_length(L1,L3),
    shuffle(L1,L2,L3),
    constraint(L3,Diff).

constraint([X1,X2],Diff):-
    int_0_100(X1),
    int_0_100(X2),
    diff(X1,X2,Diff).
constraint([X1,X2|Others],Diff):-
    int_0_100(X1),
    int_0_100(X2),
    diff(X1,X2,Diff),
    constraint([X2|Others],Diff).

shuffle([],L2,L2).
shuffle([X1|Others],L2,L3):-
    L4 = [X1 | L2],
    shuffle(Others,L4,L3).

diff(X1,X2,Diff):-
    X1 >= X2,
    X1 - X2 > Diff.
diff(X1,X2,Diff):-
    X1 < X2,
    X2 - X1 > Diff.    

int_0_100(N):-
    N >= 0, N =< 100.

same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|Others1],[_|Others2]):-
    same_length(Others1,Others2).
```

I guess that the problem is that I instantiate a `L4` list that can't change in the `shuffle` predicate.

Now my colleague's solution:

```
arrange(L1,L2,Diff):-
    same_length(L1,L2),
    shuffle(L1,L2),
    constraint(L2,Diff).

constraint([X1,X2],Diff):-
    int_0_100(X1),
    int_0_100(X2),
    diff(X1,X2,Diff).
constraint([X1,X2|Others],Diff):-
    int_0_100(X1),
    int_0_100(X2),
    diff(X1,X2,Diff),
    constraint([X2|Others],Diff).

shuffle([],_).
shuffle([X1|Others],L2):-
    member(X1,L2),
    shuffle(Others,L2).

diff(X1,X2,Diff):-
    X1 >= X2,
    X1 - X2 > Diff.
diff(X1,X2,Diff):-
    X1 < X2,
    X2 - X1 > Diff.    
    
int_0_100(N):-
    N >= 0, N =< 100.
   
same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|Others1],[_|Others2]):-
    same_length(Others1,Others2).
```

As you can see there is one major difference:

- In the shuffle predicate He uses `member(X1,L2)`, I use`L4 = [X1 | L2],shuffle(Other,L4,L3)`. `member(X1,L2)` gives an error if we have a list with two (or more) equal elements.
- For Example: `arrange([1,2,3,4,1], List2, 1)`. Since `member(1, L2)` is already `true` (the second time), and since `L2` has initially the same number of elements of `L1` (but not instantiated) with `same_length`, it doesn't add another `1` in `L2` and when we get to `int_0_100` we get an `element not enough instantiated` error.

This is the problem I was trying to fix, but it seems that if I don't specifically use `member`, instead of my solution, it just gives one possible answer.

Can you explain to me why that is, and a possible solution of the problem that the predicate `member` gives?

Thanks in advance for your time, I hope everything's clear enough: English is not my native language, and the problem itself is quite complicated to explain.

Comment: Is that not a permutation of the list? See [permutation/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation/2)

Comment: @GuyCoder: of course, using permutation/2, forall/2,append/3 and abs/1 it's one liner...

Comment: See my comment above where I answer @GuyCoder question. Could you turn it into a solution for your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one looks at the "shuffles" and extracts them:

```
% Your shuffle:

shuffle_a(LI,LO) :-
   shuffle_help(LI,[],LO).

shuffle_help([],L2,L2).
shuffle_help([X1|Other],L2,L3):-
    shuffle_help(Other,[X1|L2],L3).


% Colleague's shuffle

shuffle_b([],_).
shuffle_b([X1|Others],L2):-
    member(X1,L2),
    shuffle_b(Others,L2).
```

then one sees that your shuffle just reverses the list on first argument position, whereas your colleague's "shuffle" indeed shuffles:

Note that both shuffle predicates have to be called with a list of the correct length on second argument position:

```
?- shuffle_a([1,2,3],[S1,S2,S3]).
S1 = 3,
S2 = 2,
S3 = 1.
```

```
?- shuffle_b([1,2,3],[S1,S2,S3]).
S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 3 ;
S1 = 1, S2 = 3, S3 = 2 ;
S1 = 2, S2 = 1, S3 = 3 ;
S1 = 3, S2 = 1, S3 = 2 ;
S1 = 2, S2 = 3, S3 = 1 ;
S1 = 3, S2 = 2, S3 = 1 ;
false.
```

In `shuffle_a/2` there is only one way to proceed at any point.

But in `shuffle_b/2`, the `member/2` call is able to pick one of N possible elements `X1` out of the list `L2` of length N. So one can tell Prolog to "redo" its choice and pick another element.

Same as

```
?- member(X,[1,2,3]).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

which gives three possible answers.

## Addendum

In order to correctly permute the list use [permutation/2](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2) as Guy Coder says or maybe proceed like this: A `shuffle_c` that uses a list of indexes *0...N-1* given to `member/2` to track picking elements from the original list exactly once, and then uses `nth0/3` to unify elements of the first and second list:

```
shuffle_c(List,OtherList) :-
   same_length(List,OtherList),
   length(List,Length),
   build_index_list(Length,IndexList),
   shuffle_by_index(IndexList,[],List,OtherList).
      
build_index_list(Length,IndexList) :-
   LengthAdj is Length-1,
   bagof(Index,between(0,LengthAdj,Index),IndexList).
    
% shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,List,OtherList).

shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,_,_) :- 
   same_length(IndexList,UsedIndexList).    % Success, shuffle_c will succeed with another answer
   
shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,List,OtherList) :- 
   \+ same_length(IndexList,UsedIndexList), % Not done yet
   member(ToIndex,IndexList),               % Pick an "ToIndex" from IndexList
   \+member(ToIndex,UsedIndexList),         % ...that hasn't been used yet
   length(UsedIndexList,FromIndex),         % The "FromIndex" is just monotonically increasing
   format("'to index' = ~d, 'from index' = ~d. The used index list is currently: ~q~n",[ToIndex,FromIndex,UsedIndexList]),   
   nth0(FromIndex,List,X),                  % Unifies List[FromIndex] and
   nth0(ToIndex,OtherList,X),               % OtherList[ToIndex]
   shuffle_by_index(IndexList,[ToIndex|UsedIndexList],List,OtherList).
```

No special handling for identical elements in the original list is done.

This actually works for any of the lists uninstantiated:

```
?- bagof(List,
        shuffle_c(List,[1,2,3,4]),
        Bag).


Bag = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2],
       [1,4,2,3],[1,4,3,2],[2,1,3,4],[2,1,4,3],
       [2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1],[2,4,1,3],[2,4,3,1],
       [3,1,2,4],[3,1,4,2],[3,2,1,4],[3,2,4,1],
       [3,4,1,2],[3,4,2,1],[4,1,2,3],[4,1,3,2],
       [4,2,1,3],[4,2,3,1],[4,3,1,2],[4,3,2,1]].
```

And

```
?- bagof(List,
         shuffle_c([1,2,3,4],List),
         Bag).

Bag = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,3,2,4],[1,4,2,3],
       [1,3,4,2],[1,4,3,2],[2,1,3,4],[2,1,4,3],
       [3,1,2,4],[4,1,2,3],[3,1,4,2],[4,1,3,2],
       [2,3,1,4],[2,4,1,3],[3,2,1,4],[4,2,1,3],
       [3,4,1,2],[4,3,1,2],[2,3,4,1],[2,4,3,1],
       [3,2,4,1],[4,2,3,1],[3,4,2,1],[4,3,2,1]].
```

This even works for "lists of uninstantiated elements". Feels like shuffling holes. Let's see what happens if two holes are identical

```
?- bagof(List,shuffle_c([A,X,X,D],List),Bag).

Bag = [[A,X,X,D],[A,X,D,X],[A,X,X,D],[A,D,X,X],
       [A,X,D,X],[A,D,X,X],[X,A,X,D],[X,A,D,X],
       [X,A,X,D],[D,A,X,X],[X,A,D,X],[D,A,X,X],
       [X,X,A,D],[X,D,A,X],[X,X,A,D],[D,X,A,X],
       [X,D,A,X],[D,X,A,X],[X,X,D,A],[X,D,X,A],
       [X,X,D,A],[D,X,X,A],[X,D,X,A],[D,X,X,A]].
```

This can be easily adapted to solve the original problem. We can use constraints (i.e. `libray(clpfd)`): We set up a constraint among subsequent elements `A`, `B` of the target list enforcing the constraint:

```
abs(A - B) #> K
```

Whenever an unification during shuffle is attempted that would violate that constraint, the unification will fail, i.e. the
call `nth0(ToIndex,OtherList,X)` will fail for reasons that are not apparent from the code alone: because the currently live constraints veto it.

In the tracer, one sees

```
Call: (14) lists:nth0(1,[50,33,11,78],_40136) ? creep
Exit: (14) lists:nth0(1,[50,33,11,78],33) ? creep
Call: (14) lists:nth0(1,[50,_34818{clpfd = ...},_35522{clpfd = ...},_36226{clpfd = ...}],33) ? creep
Fail: (14) lists:nth0(1,[50,_34818{clpfd = ...},_35522{clpfd = ...},_36226{clpfd = ...}],33) ? creep
```

So, the new code (not bothering about the "must be between 0 and 100" constraint here) (one can probably do it even simpler as there is a ready-made 'permutation' constraint IIRC):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

arrange(List,OtherList,K) :-
   same_length(List,OtherList),
   apply_constraints(OtherList,K), % <----- HERE
   length(List,Length),
   build_index_list(Length,IndexList),
   shuffle_by_index(IndexList,[],List,OtherList).

% ADD THIS
      
apply_constraints([_],_).
apply_constraints([A,B|More],K) :-
   abs(A - B) #> K,
   apply_constraints([B|More],K).

% NOTHING BELOW HAS CHANGED

build_index_list(Length,IndexList) :-
   LengthAdj is Length-1,
   bagof(Index,between(0,LengthAdj,Index),IndexList).
    
% shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,List,OtherList).

shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,_,_) :- 
   same_length(IndexList,UsedIndexList).    % Success, shuffle_c will succeed with another answer
   
shuffle_by_index(IndexList,UsedIndexList,List,OtherList) :- 
   \+ same_length(IndexList,UsedIndexList), % Not done yet
   member(ToIndex,IndexList),               % Pick an "ToIndex" from IndexList
   \+member(ToIndex,UsedIndexList),         % ...that hasn't been used yet
   length(UsedIndexList,FromIndex),         % The "FromIndex" is just monotonically increasing
   format("'to index' = ~d, 'from index' = ~d. The used index list is currently: ~q~n",[ToIndex,FromIndex,UsedIndexList]),   
   nth0(FromIndex,List,X),                  % Unifies List[FromIndex] and
   nth0(ToIndex,OtherList,X),               % OtherList[ToIndex]
   shuffle_by_index(IndexList,[ToIndex|UsedIndexList],List,OtherList).
```

And so:

```
?- bagof(List,arrange([50,33,11,78],List,20),Bag).

Bag = [[50,11,33,78],[50,78,33,11],[50,11,78,33],
       [50,78,11,33],[11,50,78,33],[78,50,11,33],
       [33,11,50,78],[33,78,50,11],[33,11,78,50],
       [33,78,11,50],[11,33,78,50],[78,33,11,50]].
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way (in the second solution) to avoid the Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error, which happens when giving a list with two (or more) equals elements as input? Since member(Elem, List) fails if Elem is already in the list, an element remains NOT instantiated and when checking for the [0..100] range of the element you get the error.   

e.g. arrange([1,2,3,1], List).

Comment: @BlueRyse Actually member/2 succeeds as expected when the first list has two identicall elements. However, as used, it maps the two elements to the same element in the second list. Suppose there are two `1`: on the first encounter, member/2 selects the first uninstantiated element found in the second list and unifies it with `1`. When the second `1` is found, member doesn't pick the first uninstantaited element because it is happy with picking the `1` instead, which comes earlier. This leaves an uninstantiated element et the end.

Comment: Yes and that's a problem because a list with two or more equals elements would be a proper input List. What can I use instead of member/2, that picks both the 1 in your example?

Comment: @BlueRyse Hold on, composing something

Comment: @BlueRyse Check it out